# How do I extract specific values from a mySQL table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

So I've connected to my mySQL database, and I am able to view all of the columns within the table that I'm looking to extract information from. Now I need to be able to read all of the values, from specific fields within "ds_users" which are "password"  and "username". I'd like to store these into an array and print them out. Here's the code that I have so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ds_users");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

also, is there a way to print the results in JSON format?

Comment: Sorry, but I see no question here that a brief visit to the PHP manual could leave unanswered for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Okay, cool. I saw that online, but I was a little confused with all of the JSON encoding options that were available. Thank you!

Comment: What about `("SELECT username,password FROM ds_users")` then loop through? Or `("SELECT * FROM ds_users where username=? AND password=?")` unless I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, that's exactly it. It turns out that I had a syntax error the whole time so I thought I was doing it wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM ds_users");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dataArray['user'] = $row->user;
        $dataArray['password'] = $row->password;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($dataArray));
}
```

On side note: mysql functions are deprecated, you should choose between mysqli or PDO.

Comment: There might be a syntax error somewhere? I can quite get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)() in php

```
$arr = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}

print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

To store in array

```
    $dataArray = array();
     if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $dataArray[] = $row;
        }
    }
```

Convert into JSON format using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function

```
 $jsonString = json_encode($dataArray);
```